# Android - How to change color in setColor

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

I want to create a drawing app, and it works clearly but it is still far away from my goal.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DrawingView dv;
    private Paint mPaint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        dv = new DrawingView(this);
        setContentView(dv);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    public class DrawingView extends View {

        public int width;
        public int height;
        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Path mPath;
        private Paint mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;

        public DrawingView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context = c;
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePath = new Path();
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.asd) //-->here load your image
                    .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;

                circlePath.reset();
                circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            circlePath.reset();
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}


public class FingerPaintActivity extends Activity
        implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener{

    MyView mv;
    AlertDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mv= new MyView(this);
        mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.afor);//set the back ground if you wish to
        setContentView(mv);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;
        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Path mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context=c;
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.asd) //-->here load your image
                    .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            //showDialog();
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
            //mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my app looks like:

[image: preview my app, you can check and you will be understand what i mean]

1. I want to change color draw from blue to brown. I changed `mPaint.setColor(Color.BROWN);` and it failed.
2. If you check my preview app, you'll see that I want to create a business logic where: If user is drawing and it's not completed, the app will show a message like "sorry you have not finished the drawing" and I still look for the way to do it. I don't know if it's possible, is it?

Comment: can't say about how to determine if path has been fully drawn or not but you say that that you failed changing color. Can you explain properly what does fail means ? any error or something. currently it is quite hard to help since you have posted very long code here. Focus on only relevant part and asking a specific question please.

Comment: in my code, there is code to setColor.
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE) ---> it just works for setColor red,green,blue,magenta,cyan. and if i change that code to mPaint.setColor(Color.BROWN) -->  and i run this app, it just show the canvas and cant be colored. can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following line:

```
mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color));
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that your main question is how to change color programmatically, right?

just change:

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.BROWN);
```

to:

```
mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Brown));
```

I think it can help you